# _asm in which cases is it best to use it?

Tags: c, windows, assembly, inline-assembly

I will risk a question, sorry if the question is simple.

Currently, I am refreshing the knowledge of C. I was browsing a book and found something completely new for me, namely the keyword "__asm", can anyone share their experiences, where did the need to use it come from or in what cases can it be used?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info has some pointers.

Comment: Oh, ok. That's enough, but I must admit that I searched the prompts and this post was not displayed to me.

Comment: Generally https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm if you can avoid it.  There aren't a lot of good use-cases.  Notably for Windows, MSVC has intrinsics for basically everything including privileged instructions, although with other compilers (like gcc/clang where you'd use `__asm__()` or `asm()`) you could need it for instructions that don't have intrinsics.